# Convert string of accounting data into integers (positive and negative)

Tags: regex, r

I have a data formatted in the "accounting" style from Excel that look like `($317.40)` or `$13,645.48`. As a regexp newbie, I'm looking for a more efficient way of removing all useless symbols and converting strings with parentheses into negative numbers.

Here's how I've been doing it so far:

```
spending$Amount <- gsub("^[(]", "-", spending$Amount)
spending$Amount <- gsub("[$]", "", spending$Amount)
spending$Amount <- gsub("[)]", "", spending$Amount)
spending$Amount <- as.numeric(gsub("[,]", "", spending$Amount))
```

Can I do this in one line? Is there a specialized R package that can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nested `gsub` solution

```
x <- c("($317.40)", "$13,645.48")
as.numeric(gsub("\\(", "-", gsub("\\)|\\$|,", "", x)))
## [1]  -317.40 13645.48


## Really convoluted bad way of doing it solution 
mapply(FUN = function(x,y) ifelse(x,-1,1)*as.numeric(paste(y,collapse="")), grepl('\\(',x) ,regmatches(x, gregexpr('[0-9\\.]+',x)) )
```

Comment: if i have to do it other way round.. replace negative values with braces what should i do?